# Remove background header image in mobile view on certain page on Squarespace website

Tags: css, header, position, background-image, squarespace

The website url is: http://www.georjart.com/paintings-new

The password is: M6NYey7f

I've added a background image to the header of a specific page on this Squarespace website above using the following code:

```
#collection-6058d724f45e96664a810213 header#header {
    background-image: url(https://www.emergentcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Gart-BG-Header-Example-1-2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    padding: 40px
}
```

However when I go to mobile view it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I can see that the issue is with the "position" and "background-image" code and by going into Dev Tools in Chrome I can edit the following media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px)
#header {
    background-image: none !important;
    position: inherit !important;

}
```

I can get it too look normal:

[image]

However I'm not certain how to add this code into the CSS editor in Squarespace, let alone on a specific page which is what I'd like to do since the changes aren't live yet.

Does anyone have a solution?

Cheers,

M.

Answer (score 0):

Using your approach of an absolutely-positioned header as a starting point (and without reworking that approach), I would do the following in place of what you have now.

```
#collection-6058d724f45e96664a810213 #header {
  background-image: url("https://www.emergentcreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Gart-BG-Header-Example-1-2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 750.1px) {
  #collection-6058d724f45e96664a810213 #header {
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    padding: 40px
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  #collection-6058d724f45e96664a810213 #header {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
}
```